# JSON decode of 1 failed

Tags: litecoin

Trying to mine using cudaminer but I keep getting JSON error 1, here is the batch file

```
cudaminer.exe -H 1 -i 1 -l T9x20 -C 2 or -H 1 -i 1 -l T12x32 -c 1 -o stratum+tcp://global.wemineltc.com:3333 -u omarqureshi.1 -p x -I 13
```